# In ubuntu, are there some commands mean "append" and "include" ?? please show me

Tags: ubuntu

i am beginning learn to use Ubuntu by myself and i don't understand this sentence:

...Then, append your ~/.bashrc file to include the following lines:

```
   "# virtualenv and virtualenvwrappe
    export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
    export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
    source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh"
```

...

What are "append" and "include" mean ???
It is Ubuntu so is that some commands ???
Anyone know them, the commands "append" and "include" ???
please explain to me, thanks, many thanks

Comment: It means "copy/paste these lines to the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file"

Answer (score 0):

It means to literally put these lines at the end of your .bashrc file, which is located in your home directory.

If you have a file lines.txt in your home directory you could simply issue

```
cd ~
cat lines.txt >> .bashrc
```

Or you could use any text editor, of course.

Note that the .bashrc file is executed by the shell. Only put code in there that you trust not to be harmful.

Comment: i think bashrc is a hidden file and only accessed by terminal . that's reason i think the actions are commands. Like you said, seem i need create a file like the lines.txt then use the command you suggested ???

Comment: @ConBốPhong your user interface should have the option to show hidden files.